# using a batch to copy single file into subfolders and their subfolders and so on

Tags: batch-file

I'm curious if that task a have to perform is achievable by using a batch.
I have to copy a single file into multiple subfolder which have also subfolders the file has to be copied to as well.
Using a batch, the input would look something like this:

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in ("C:\\Users\\thomas\\Desktop\\Battest\*.\*") do xcopy /y /d C:\\Users\\thomas\\Desktop\\Battest\\indextest.php "%%a"
```

This would only copy the index.php into the first subfolder, which are directly on the next level.
Since the index.php needs to be copied into 700 folders and I don't know all the concrete directory paths, I'm not sure how to handle this using a wildcard or if this task is even achievable like this.

I've tried to utilize a batch to copy a single file into multiple subfolders, which path I don't know. So far I just managed to copy the file onto the 1st subfolders.

Here is the cmd output to show the directional structure. You can see that there is an index.php in every folder which needs to be **replaced** (I didn't specify that before. sorry):

```
C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists>dir
 Datenträger in Laufwerk C: ist Windows
 Volumeseriennummer: 3C59-5A60

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          01_Sealing Guide
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          02_Precast Concrete Plant Catalogue
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          03_Structural and Civil Engineering Catalogue
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          04_Price list
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          05_Press Releases
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          06_News
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          07_Consulting Catalogue
23.03.2022  16:26             3.627 index.php
               1 Datei(en),          3.627 Bytes
               9 Verzeichnis(se), 343.890.636.800 Bytes frei

C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists>dir /s
 Datenträger in Laufwerk C: ist Windows
 Volumeseriennummer: 3C59-5A60

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          01_Sealing Guide
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          02_Precast Concrete Plant Catalogue
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          03_Structural and Civil Engineering Catalogue
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          04_Price list
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          05_Press Releases
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          06_News
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          07_Consulting Catalogue
23.03.2022  16:26             3.627 index.php
               1 Datei(en),          3.627 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\01_Sealing Guide

25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          ..
25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          English
25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          French
25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          German
23.03.2022  16:26             3.627 index.php
25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          Russian
25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          Spanish
               1 Datei(en),          3.627 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\01_Sealing Guide\English

25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          ..
02.10.2020  14:14         2.393.613 BTi_Catalogue_Sealing Guide_EN_2020-09.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),      2.395.719 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\01_Sealing Guide\French

25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          ..
07.05.2021  08:53         2.997.413 BTi_Sealing Guide_FR_2020-09.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),      2.999.519 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\01_Sealing Guide\German

25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          ..
17.06.2021  09:27         2.872.797 BTi_Abdichtungsguide_DE_2020-09.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),      2.874.903 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\01_Sealing Guide\Russian

25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          ..
07.05.2021  08:42         3.039.947 BTi_Руководство по герметизации_RU_09-2020.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),      3.042.053 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\01_Sealing Guide\Spanish

25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          ..
13.12.2021  11:34         3.560.598 BTi_Katalog_Abdichtung_ES_2021-12_web.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),      3.562.704 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\02_Precast Concrete Plant Catalogue

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          English
25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          French
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          German
23.03.2022  16:26             3.627 index.php
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          Polish
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          Russian
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          Spanish
               1 Datei(en),          3.627 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\02_Precast Concrete Plant Catalogue\English

25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          ..
07.10.2020  08:27         9.967.701 BTi_Catalogue_Precast Concrete Plant_EN_2020-09.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),      9.969.807 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\02_Precast Concrete Plant Catalogue\French

25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:53    <DIR>          ..
10.07.2020  15:01         9.737.367 BTi_Catalogue_Precast Concrete Plant_FR_2020_07.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),      9.739.473 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\02_Precast Concrete Plant Catalogue\German

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
10.07.2020  12:34        10.145.406 BTi_Katalog_Betonfertigteilwerk_DE_2020-07.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),     10.147.512 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\02_Precast Concrete Plant Catalogue\Polish

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
10.07.2020  15:35        10.116.783 BTi_Catalogue_Precast Concrete Plant_PL_2020-07.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),     10.118.889 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\02_Precast Concrete Plant Catalogue\Russian

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
11.08.2020  07:53         5.882.519 BTi_Catalogue_Precast Concret Plant_RU_2020-07_web.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),      5.884.625 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\02_Precast Concrete Plant Catalogue\Spanish

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
10.07.2020  14:24         9.857.478 BTi_Catalogue_Structural and Civil Engineering_ES_2020-07.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),      9.859.584 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\03_Structural and Civil Engineering Catalogue

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          English
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          French
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          German
23.03.2022  16:26             3.627 index.php
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          Russian
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          Spanish
               1 Datei(en),          3.627 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\03_Structural and Civil Engineering Catalogue\English

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
26.07.2019  12:49         7.243.746 BTi_Catalogue_Structural and Civil Engineering_EN_2019-07.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
11.12.2019  08:36               283 Web_Version.url
               3 Datei(en),      7.246.135 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\03_Structural and Civil Engineering Catalogue\French

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
25.09.2019  09:04         5.916.375 BTi_Catalogue_Structural and Civil Engineering_FR_2019-09.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),      5.918.481 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\03_Structural and Civil Engineering Catalogue\German

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
25.07.2019  08:46         7.284.669 BTi_Katalog_Produktkatalog Hoch- und Tiefbau_DE_2019-07.pdf
16.11.2021  16:09        12.879.830 BTi_Katalog_Schalungstechnik_Syflex_DE_2021-11.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
11.12.2019  08:34               267 Web-Version.url
               4 Datei(en),     20.166.872 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\03_Structural and Civil Engineering Catalogue\Russian

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
11.08.2020  07:54         3.245.824 BTi_Catalogue_Structural and Civil Engineering_RU_2019-11_web.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),      3.247.930 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\03_Structural and Civil Engineering Catalogue\Spanish

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
27.03.2020  13:00         7.493.352 BTi_Catalogue_Structural and Civil Engineering_ES_2020-03.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),      7.495.458 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\04_Price list

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
23.03.2022  16:26             3.627 index.php
               1 Datei(en),          3.627 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\05_Press Releases

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          English
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          French
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          German
23.03.2022  16:26             3.627 index.php
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          Russian
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          Spanish
               1 Datei(en),          3.627 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\05_Press Releases\English

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
26.04.2021  09:02        11.764.334 BTi_Press Kit_EN_2021-04.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),     11.766.440 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\05_Press Releases\French

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
26.04.2021  10:11         8.163.842 BTi_Dossier de presse_FR_2021-04.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),      8.165.948 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\05_Press Releases\German

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
30.03.2021  12:46           585.743 30 Jahre B.T innovation_de.pdf
04.03.2021  09:38        12.443.367 BTi_Pressemappe_DE_2021-03.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               3 Datei(en),     13.031.216 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\05_Press Releases\Russian

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
26.04.2021  09:42         7.846.420 BTi_Press Kit_RU_2021-04.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),      7.848.526 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\05_Press Releases\Spanish

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
26.04.2021  10:05         7.596.592 BTi_Kit de prensa_SP_2021-04.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),      7.598.698 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\06_News

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
08.06.2021  14:06           461.634 BTi_Important Information Regarding Prises and Offers 06-08-2021.pdf
23.03.2021  08:59           328.846 BTi_Price Increase for MultiForm starting 04-01-2021.pdf
23.03.2021  09:00           320.885 BTi_Price increase for shuttering magnets starting 05-01-2021.pdf
23.03.2022  16:26             3.627 index.php
07.03.2022  12:20           368.344 Price Increase BT-Spannschloss® (Turnbuckle) - BT innovation.pdf
31.01.2022  15:40           493.366 Price increase for RubberElast - BT innovation.pdf
25.01.2022  08:13           112.744 Price Increase GRP Products - BT innovation.pdf
               7 Datei(en),      2.089.446 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\07_Consulting Catalogue

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          English
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          German
23.03.2022  16:26             3.627 index.php
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          Russian
               1 Datei(en),          3.627 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\07_Consulting Catalogue\English

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
24.11.2021  11:27        14.069.238 BTi_Catalogue_Consulting_EN_2021-10_web.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),     14.071.344 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\07_Consulting Catalogue\German

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
25.11.2021  13:37        14.651.703 BTi_Produktkatalog_consulting_DE_2021-10_Web.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),     14.653.809 Bytes

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\01_General Catalogues and Price Lists\07_Consulting Catalogue\Russian

25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          .
25.03.2022  07:54    <DIR>          ..
25.11.2021  09:10        11.576.341 BTi_Catalogue_Consulting_RU_web.pdf
28.04.2021  15:43             2.106 index.php
               2 Datei(en),     11.578.447 Bytes

     Anzahl der angezeigten Dateien:
              66 Datei(en),    205.498.927 Bytes
              95 Verzeichnis(se), 343.888.109.568 Bytes frei
```

Comment: What are the destination directories, the immediate children of `Battest`, or the grandchildren, or both, or the whole sub-directory tree?

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `tree /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, to find out how to use the command you'll need to show us the exact directory structure. Submit the pertinent part of the output from that command, within a code box, by [edit]ing your question, and incude within it an indication of where you'd like your files copied to. We need to fully understand your task before we can offer an efficient, and robust, solution for you. I will add however, that an efficient solution would not use the built-in `forfiles` executable. Please also submit a [mcve] of the code you have tried.

Comment: not specifically documented, but you can combine the `/d` switch with the `/r` switch (**r**ecursive). `for /d /r %%a ...` or `for /d /r "z:\start\folder" %%a ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the exact scenario, there are several possibilities:

1. (Re-)Placing file `indextest.php` in immediate children of root directory `%UserProfile%\Desktop\Battest`:

   ```cmd
    for /D %%J in ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\Battest\*") do (
        xcopy /Y /D "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Battest\indextest.php" "%%~J"
    )
   ```
2. (Re-)Placing file `indextest.php` in grand-children of root directory `%UserProfile%\Desktop\Battest`:

   ```cmd
    for /D %%J in ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\Battest\*") do (
        for /D %%I in ("%%~J\*") do (
            xcopy /Y /D "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Battest\indextest.php" "%%~I"
        )
    )
   ```
3. (Re-)Placing file `indextest.php` in children and grand-children of root directory `%UserProfile%\Desktop\Battest`:

   ```cmd
    for /D %%J in ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\Battest\*") do (
        xcopy /Y /D "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Battest\indextest.php" "%%~J"
        for /D %%I in ("%%~J\*") do (
            xcopy /Y /D "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Battest\indextest.php" "%%~I"
        )
    )
   ```
4. (Re-)Placing file `indextest.php` in all descendants of root directory `%UserProfile%\Desktop\Battest`:

   ```cmd
    for /D /R "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Battest" %%J in (*) do (
        xcopy /Y /D "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Battest\indextest.php" "%%~J"
    )
   ```

You may replace the command `xcopy /Y /D` with `replace /U` in order to avoid addition of file `indextest.php` in sub-directories that do not yet contain such.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do that with `forfiles`? Something like (not tested):

```
FORFILES /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE xcopy /y /d C:\Users\...\indextest.php @path"
```

Comment: Well, using `forfiles` is mostly a bad idea, because it is slow, faulty and utterly complicated. The only justification of existence of this ugly command is its `/D` option, although even that one needs to be used with care…

Answer (score 0):

```
for /r "C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\Battest" %%a in (.) do if /i "%%~dpa" neq "C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\Battest\" ECHO xcopy /y /d C:\Users\thomas\Desktop\Battest\indextest.php "%%a"
```

Should `echo` the copy command for **each** subdirectory of the directory nominated after the `/r`.

Obviously, remove the `echo` keyword after verification to actually execute the `xcopy`.

See `for /?` from the prompt for details.

Comment: I did try your code using the cmd. And it did indeed work. The index.php got copied to all the folder as intended. However, since I didn't specify that, I have to replace existing index.php. So I went ahead and used `for /r "C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\Battest" %a in (.) do replace /r /s C:\Users\thomasb\Desktop\Battest\indextest.php "%a"` which did work for my test folder. Then I tried applying that method to the real project folder. It did not work. I'll get back to this post when I've got more information.

Comment: @BermudaRhythm, `for /R` is already recursive, so `replace /R` is redundant and probably causes troubles. The only issue with this code is the very first iteration which tries to copy a file onto itself, but this does not affect further iterations…

Comment: @aschipfl : fixed. I believe. @bermudaRhythm: `xcopy /y` should overwrite any existing `indextest.php` in the directory.

Comment: Seems I confused `replace /R` (replace read-only files) with `replace /S` (recurse into sub-directories, the latter of which I actually do not recommend together with `for /R`…